# Flatpickr redraws the days list after selecting a day and all changes made with onDayCreate are lost

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flatpickr

I wrote a Vue.js component for displaying a customized calendar with different background colors of days. And after selecting any day, all my changes are lost, because Flatpickr redraws days DOM elements. How I can repeat the actions of the `onDayCreate` callback when the days grid is updated?

```html
<script>
import { UI_DATE_FORMAT } from "../data/System";
import flatPickr from "vue-flatpickr-component";
import RequestService from "../services/RequestService";

const request = new RequestService();

export default {
  props: [],

  data() {
    return {
      selectedDate: "",
      currentMonth: null,
      busyDaysData: {},
      updateDataProcess: false,

      dateConfig: {
        inline: true,
        dateFormat: UI_DATE_FORMAT,
        monthSelectorType: "static",
        wrap: false,

        onDayCreate: function (dObj, dStr, fp, dayElem) {
          this.calendarDayCreate(dayElem, fp);
        }.bind(this),
      },
    };
  },

  components: {
    flatPickr,
  },

  mounted() {},

  methods: {
    calendarDayCreate(dayElem, fp) {
      const month = fp.currentMonth + 1;
      const dayDay = dayElem.dateObj.getDate();
      const dayMonth = dayElem.dateObj.getMonth() + 1;

      if (dayMonth !== month) return;

      if (this.updateDataProcess) {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
          if (!this.updateDataProcess) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            this.handleDay(dayDay, dayElem);
          }
        }, 250);
      } else {
        if (this.currentMonth !== month) {
          this.updateDataProcess = true;

          new Promise((onSuccess, onError) => {
            request.requestData(
              {
                data: "Calendar\\BusyDaysForMonth",
                arguments: {
                  appointment_id: 0,
                  month,
                  extended: true,
                },
              },
              (response) => {
                onSuccess(response);
              },
              (error) => {
                onError(error);
              }
            );
          }).then(
            (response) => {
              this.updateDataProcess = false;

              this.currentMonth = month;
              this.busyDaysData = response.data;
              this.handleDay(dayDay, dayElem);
            },
            (error) => {
              this.updateDataProcess = false;
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
        }
      }
    },

    handleDay(day, dayElem) {
      if (!this.busyDaysData[day]) return;
      console.log(dayElem);
      dayElem.classList.add(
        "app-" + this.busyDaysData[day].appointment_status ?? ""
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <b-row id="appointments-calendar">
    <b-col cols="12">
      <flat-pickr
        :config="dateConfig"
        v-model="selectedDate"
        class="form-control flatpickr active"
        :placeholder="$t('appointments_input_date_ph')"
      >
      </flat-pickr>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

[image: Before select]

[image: After select]

I tried different event hooks from the documentation (*[Events & Hooks](https://flatpickr.js.org/events/#events)*), but they do not give the same possibility for setting up days elements like the `onDayCreate` function.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I need to add a condition if the month has not changed.

```
if (this.currentMonth !== month) {
    this.updateDataProcess = true;

    new Promise((onSuccess, onError) => {
        request.requestData({
            data: 'Calendar\\BusyDaysForMonth',
            arguments: {
                appointment_id: 0,
                month,
                extended: true,
            },
        },
        (response) => { onSuccess(response) },
        (error) => { onError(error) });
    }).then(
        (response) => {
            this.updateDataProcess = false;

            this.currentMonth = month;
            this.busyDaysData = response.data;
            this.handleDay(dayDay, dayElem);
        },
        (error) => {
            this.updateDataProcess = false;
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
} else {
    this.handleDay(dayDay, dayElem);
}
```